# Many-many relationship, PK not unique

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I've got a many-many relationship that is being handled by an intersection table.

foo(**foo_id**, foo_name)

bar(**bar_id**, bar_name)

foo_bar_intersect(**foo_id**, **bar_id**)

I am creating a view on top of the foo_bar_intersect which shows each name.

`CREATE VIEW foo_bar_view AS
    SELECT foo.foo_name, bar.bar_name
    FROM foo_bar_intersect
    INNER JOIN foo ON foo.foo_id = foo_bar_intersect.foo_id
    INNER JOIN bar ON bar.bar_id = foo_bar_intersect.bar_id`

But I am getting two identical entries in the results, when I shouldn't, since (foo_id, bar_id) is the PK of foo_bar_intersect.

Comment: are you sure your data doesn't have foo_name and bar_name duplicated.  the ID's could be unique, but the names don't have to be.  `Select foo_name, count(foo_id) from foo group by foo_name having count(foo_ID) > 1` and the similar for bar... any results may explain the problem

Comment: You were totally right. That hadn't occurred to me due to the design of the database. It still _shouldn't_ happen, but this has at least focused my attention. Thanks.

Comment: If foo_name and bar_name is supposed to be unique, add a constraint that enforces the uniqueness. i.e. `alter table foo add constraint ak_foo unique (foo_name)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your data doesn't have foo_name and bar_name duplicated. The ID's could be unique, but the names don't have to be.

```
Select foo_name, count(foo_id) from foo group by foo_name having count(foo_ID) > 1
```

and the similar for bar... any results may explain the problem